# How to convert json to pyspark dataframe (faster implementation)

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have json data in form of 
{'abc':1, 'def':2, 'ghi':3}
How to convert it into pyspark dataframe in python?

Answer (score 13):

```
import json
j = {'abc':1, 'def':2, 'ghi':3}
a=[json.dumps(j)]
jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(a)
df = spark.read.json(jsonRDD)

>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+
|abc|def|ghi|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is solving the question. But its very slow. It takes 100 ms just to convert from json to dataframe. it is increasing API roundtrip time. Is there faster way?

Comment: data = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}]

df = sql_context.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()