# How to covert the nested json to datafarme

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the json data and I want to convert the json data into dataframe

```
[
{FlierNumber:,BaggageTypeReturn:,FirstName:K,Title:1,MiddleName:D,LastName:Gupta,MealTypeOnward:,DateOfBirth:,BaggageTypeOnward:,SeatTypeOnward:,MealTypeReturn:,FrequentAirline:null,Type:A,SeatTypeReturn:},
{FlierNumber:,BaggageTypeReturn:,FirstName:Sweety,Title:2,MiddleName:,LastName:Gupta,MealTypeOnward:,DateOfBirth:,BaggageTypeOnward:,SeatTypeOnward:,MealTypeReturn:,FrequentAirline:null,Type:A,SeatTypeReturn:}
]
```

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456076/how-to-convert-json-to-pyspark-dataframe-faster-implementation

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you gave above is invalid. Here is the syntactically correct JSON format

```
[{"FlierNumber":"","BaggageTypeReturn":"","FirstName":"K","Title":"1","MiddleName":"D","LastName":"Gupta","MealTypeOnward":"","DateOfBirth":"","BaggageTypeOnward":"","SeatTypeOnward":"","MealTypeReturn":"","FrequentAirline":"null","Type":"A","SeatTypeReturn":""},{"FlierNumber":"","BaggageTypeReturn":"","FirstName":"Sweety","Title":"2","MiddleName":"","LastName":"Gupta","MealTypeOnward":"","DateOfBirth":"","BaggageTypeOnward":"","SeatTypeOnward":"","MealTypeReturn":"","FrequentAirline":"null","Type":"A","SeatTypeReturn":""}]
```

If it is present in a file you can read in spark directly using

```
  val jsonDF = spark.read.json("filepath\sample.json")
  jsonDF.printSchema()
  jsonDF.show
```

**Result is:**

```
root
 |-- BaggageTypeOnward: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BaggageTypeReturn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DateOfBirth: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FlierNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FrequentAirline: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MealTypeOnward: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MealTypeReturn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MiddleName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SeatTypeOnward: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SeatTypeReturn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Type: string (nullable = true)


+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----+----+
|BaggageTypeOnward|BaggageTypeReturn|DateOfBirth|FirstName|FlierNumber|FrequentAirline|LastName|MealTypeOnward|MealTypeReturn|MiddleName|SeatTypeOnward|SeatTypeReturn|Title|Type|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----+----+
|                 |                 |           |        K|           |           null|   Gupta|              |              |         D|              |              |    1|   A|
|                 |                 |           |   Sweety|           |           null|   Gupta|              |              |          |              |              |    2|   A|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------+--------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------------+--------------+-----+----+
```